# Appending images using ImageMagick convert

Tags: graphics, bitmap, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

So I have a bunch of images that I wish to append vertically:

```
convert *.png -append output.png
```

However I ran into two problems:

1. Not all the images are of the same width. Hence images smaller in width than the widest image have white space trailing after them because they are left-aligned.
2. There's no spacing between the images.

How do you center align all the images and specify spacing between them?

Comment: What colour do you want the spacing? Or should it be transparent?

Comment: Preferably transparent.

Comment: Are you on Unix/Linux/OSX or Windows?

Comment: I work on Ubuntu 14.04. Hence Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use ImageMagick's [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) utility. Align the images with the [-gravity](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#gravity) & [-extent](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#extent) options, and adjust the spacing with [-geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#geometry).

```
montage fishscales.png circles.png verticalsaw.png \
        -tile 1x -geometry +10+10 \
        -gravity Center -extent 120 \
        out.png
```

[image: montage example]

Comment: This looks nice and simple but gives me this error: montage: unable to read font `(null)' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1127. Any ideas?

Comment: Could be an issue with how you installed freetype, or installed font library. Can you show us how your invoking text/annotation?

Comment: It works, but spaces between are 2x wider than space to outside (margin), because it add space (margin) to each image.

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be a shell script as follows:

```
1. Run a loop over all your images and find the width of the widest (using ImageMagick `identify`) - say 8 to 10 lines of shell script

2. Create a transparent "spacer image" the same width as the widest image and the height you want for vertically spacing images - one line of shell script

3. Run a loop over all your images first adding the transparent "spacer" to the bottom of the existing output image then compositing images that are narrower than your widest image onto a transparent background the width of your widest image - then appending that to the output image - maybe 15 lines of shell script.
```

Here is the output with three images:

Red=80px wide

Green=180 px wide

Blue=190px wide

[image]

Could that sort of approach work for you - I could probably code it over a day or two between other things!

Here is what I mean:

```
#!/bin/bash
# User-editable vertical spacing between images
SPACING=10

function centre() {
   echo DEBUG: Centering $1
   TEMP=$$tmp.png
   w=$(convert "$1" -ping -format "%w" info:)
   h=$(convert "$1" -ping -format "%h" info:)
   convert -size ${MAXW}x${h} xc:"rgba(0,0,0,0)" PNG32:$TEMP
   composite -resize '1x1<' -gravity center "$1" $TEMP $TEMP
   if [ $2 -eq 0 ]; then
      mv $TEMP output.png
   else
      convert output.png $TEMP -append output.png
      rm $TEMP 
   fi
}

# Step 1 - determine widest image and save width in MAXW
MAXW=0
for i in *.jpg; do
   w=$(convert "$i" -ping -format "%w" info:)
   [[ $w -gt $MAXW ]] && MAXW=$w
   echo DEBUG: Image $i width is $w
done
echo DEBUG: Widest image is $MAXW

# Step 2 - Create transparent spacer image, with width MAXW
convert -size ${MAXW}x${SPACING} xc:"rgba(0,0,0,0)" PNG32:spacer.png

# Step 3 - Build output image
n=0
for i in *.jpg; do

   # Add a vertical spacer if not first image
   [[ $n -ne 0 ]] && convert output.png spacer.png -append output.png

   # Centre image horizontally and append to output
   centre "$i" $n

   ((n++))
done
```

Another, completely different option would be to add all heights of the N images and create a transparent canvas the width of the widest image and the height of all the images combined plus (N-1)* vertical spacing. Then overlay the images into the canvas at the corrrect place - this involves more maths and less processing and reprocessing of images which could mean that this approach would lose less quality than the one I have suggested. I would do this approach with PerlMagick as it is better for math than bash.